# New to PARI/GP.. How to use PARI/GP for with h(p-1/q) mod p

Tags: pari-gp, pari

I am currently making a script for digital signature algorithm until I met a stumbling block which with a lot of trial and errors, I still can't get through it.

There are 3 integers which is stored to p,q,h.

Using the above 3, I would like to do

```
 g = h(p-1/q) mod p
```

The number of things I tried in my .gp script:

```
 1. g = mod((h(p-1)/q),p);

 2. g = h((p-1)/q) mod p;

 3. temp = h(p-1/q);
    g = mod(temp,p);
```

They all can't work and have errors. Anyone can enlighten me on using PARI/GP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.` was almost correct: you're missing a multiplication sign `*`, and the function name is `Mod`, not mod.

Try

> g = Mod(h*(p-1)/q, p)

Comment: Though if the OP wants an integer rather than something of type `Mod`,   something like `(h * (p-1) / q) % p` might work better.

Comment: You can also use `lift` to convert an INTMOD like Mod(3, 7) to a number like 3.